# SCSS files in different project folders get compiled into one CSS file

Tags: css, sass, live-sass-compiler

I have a folder with multiple projects, each project has its own folder.

The structure is like this:

```
project 1
project 2
... 
project n
dist 
sass 
index.html
```

Each project consists of a `dist` and `sass` folder.

The problem is, when I compile a Sass file for one project, all of my Sass files are compiled into `main.css`, inside the `dist` folder.

---

**Folder Structure:**

[image: Folder structure image]

---

**Compiler Output:**

[image: VS Code live sass compiler output]

Comment: Did you try to configure Live Sass Compiler? [Here is the doc.](https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-sass-compiler/blob/master/docs/settings.md)

Comment: Yes I changed savePath to "/dist/css"

Comment: Hu.. I'm not sure to understand your problem then?

Comment: The problem is that I have a folder with different projects and  most of them use scss. When root folder opend in vs code all projects main.scss files are compiled into one css file located in root/dist/css instead of root/project/dist/css. Thanks for your time, stay safe :)

Comment: Ahh I see, I think you should use a path relative to your sass files and not to root in your config. So it should be something like `~/../dist/css`

Comment: Thanks, I’ll check that out ;)